# Manage AppleTVs in Apple Profile Manager

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, apple-configurator, apple-profile-manager

I'm in a country where I don't have access to Apple Business Manager, VPP or DEP.
So I am able to configure Apple Configurator and Apple Profile Manager and it looks pretty good for iOS and macOS.
I'm now running into difficulties with tvOS.

I have many Apple TVs (4K) . They don't have a USB-C or Lightning port on them, so I don't think that I can supervise them through Apple Configurator 2.
How do I get them into Apple Profile Manager? (which is my goal)